# what does it mean by form state living inside the DOM?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

while learning the concept controlled components in Reactjs I came across this statement

controlled component: "A component which renders a form, but the source of truth for that form state lives inside of the component state rather than inside of the DOM"

what is a form state? and what does it mean by form state living inside of DOM or component?

could you please elaborate on it?

Answer (score -1):

> what is a form state?

The form state just means "the current values entered into the individual input elements of a form". They can be accessed through the individual input elements `value` property or through the `<form>` elements form data itself.

> what does it mean by form state living inside of DOM or component

It just means that if you do not explicitly store those values in react state and pass them to the `<input>` during render it will just be kept in the HTML input elements itself. If you inspect an `<input>` element in the developer console you will see, that it has a `value` prop. Uncontrolled just means that you do not explicitly pass that value to the `<input>` and that you do not handle changes to the value yourself. If you need to access that value in your code you would have to get a ref to the `<input>` and read that value.

```
function UncontrolledForm() {
  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // values are stored in the form but they can be accessed through the DOM node
    const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        foo
        <input name="foo" />
      </label>
      <label>
        bar
        <input name="bar" />
      </label>
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit withered-shape-7se4w]

Controlled on the other hand means that you "control" the value yourself by passing it to the `<input>` during render all the time.

```
function ControlledForm() {
  // values are kept in react state
  const [values, setValues] = useState({foo: '', bar: ''});

  const handleChange = event =>
    setValues(state => ({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        foo
        {/* we explicitly pass a value and onChange handler and manage the values ourself */}
        <input name="foo" value={values.foo} onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
      <label>
        bar
        <input name="bar" value={values.bar} onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit shy-monad-higi0]